# Add attributes to a NSLocalizedString with parameters

Tags: ios, localization, nslocalizedstring

I have an NSLocalizedString which says something like this:

> The house of David received 2 new offers.

Where the actual string is

> NSLocalizedString(@"The house of %@ received %i new offers", nil);

And I would like to add attributes on this string so it would look like this:

> The house of **David** received **2** new offers.

It's amazing this is so hard. I tried to search for the parameters in the string, get their location and add the attributes, but it screws up when I want to change the string to "The 2 houses of david received 2 new offers". There it will make all the "2" strings bold.

Is there a better way to do this? After searching for days online I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: How about [this](https://gist.github.com/brentdax/11546648)?

Comment: You also can use custom placeholders "<name>" and "<number>", and replace yourself the value.